# Vim Syntastic show warnings and set warning level

Tags: c++, vim, compiler-warnings, syntastic

I use Vim with syntastic to code in C++ and I see all errors but I don't get any warnings. It would be nice if I didn't have to use the compiler in the terminal just to get all compiler-messages. Some errors differ in different c++ standards so it should be possible to at least change the version of c++ to error-check for.

- How do I do I show warnings?
- How do I set the warning levels and settings as I do when I compile a program using g++?
- How do I set this up if I start using another language? If I get a specific command to run for c++, then I would be lost the next time.

I can't find how to do this from the manual at `:h syntastic`. I have only looked at the sections that I thought were relevant however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for every project,
in .vimrc in the project folder i will put something like

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options="-m32 -I ./inc -I ./inc/libs"
```

you can select **-w**, -Wno- or any warning level you want

use g:syntastic_c_compiler_options for pure C code

ofcourse you put this in the global .vimrc. here we use vim to edit code in several programming languages, so we use different .vimrc per project

Comment: So... can I just type `let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options="-Wall"` to enable warnings and it will not overwrite any of the default settings (if there are any)?

Comment: yep, i will keep 2 or 3 settings in the .vimrc, commenting out the unnecessary. use " to comment a row

Comment: Ok, nice! it seems to work for me to simply set all my usual flags in that string. Are the options you have written in the answer `-m32 -I ./inc -I ./inc/libs` relevant for me? I don't recognize any of them.

Comment: yea i just pasted my settings, you can put any valid gcc/g++ flags there. the ones you see will add include directories, and force 32bit output